# Are there any negative consequences if a python script moves/renames its parent directory?

Tags: python, github, directory

I have a github project available to others. One of the scripts, `update.py`, checks github everyday (via cron) to see if there is a newer version available.

Locally, the script is located at directory `/home/user/.Project/update.py`

If the version on github is newer, then `update.py` moves `/home/user/.Project/` to `/home/user/.OldProject/`, clones the github repo and moves/renames the downloaded repo to `/home/user/.Project/`

It has worked perfectly for me about five times, but I just realized that the script is moving itself while it is still running. Are there any unforeseen consequences to this approach, and it there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

As long as all of the code used by the script has been compiled and loaded into the Python VM there will be no issue with the source moving since it will remain resident in memory until the process ends or is replaced (or swapped out, but since it is considered dirty data it will be swapped in exactly the same). The operating system, though, may attempt to block the move operation if any files remain open during the process.

Comment: I have written the script to close all files before it finished executing, so that _shouldn't_ be an issue. However, I'm too much of a novice to know/understand if "all of the code used by the script has been compiled and loaded into the Python VM" - is there an easy way to tell?

Comment: Basically I'm saying "Don't import new modules after the move".

Comment: Thank you, you translated that to ELI5 perfectly. Cheers.